# Fancybox no nav buttons but gallery works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf, fancybox-2

I am doing my internship in a commercial website and I was asked to add Fancybox display of the image of the product. It looks nice but the nav buttons are missing. However, I can still navigate between pictures.

Yes, it is  set as a gallery and I've checked other posts, the photos must be in the same place.
But as I said, the gallery works, but there are no buttons and I'm all out of ideas.

The project uses a lot of stuff, but I'll add the places where I added my code. 
It uses Thymeleaf, Spring, bootstrap, fancybox 2.1.5, etc. and I'm currently working on IntelliJ IDE. Moreover, I can edit fancybox properties on "_main.less" of the project.

---

```
$(".zoomPic").fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'fade',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
});
```

```
<div class="bgstretch slide zoomPic"
     th:style="${'background-color: #' + image.colour}"
     th:each="image : ${product.images}" data-fancybox-group="gallery"
     th:attr="data-fancybox-href='#fancyGallery'+__${image.id}__">

  <span th:attr="data-srcset=${image.path},data-imageid=${'image' + image.id}"></span>

  <div th:id="'fancyGallery'+__${image.id}__" style="display: none;">
    <img th:src="${image.path}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

A working button is not that much needed actually. A right and left chevron floating on each side will be enough. So, I'm open for suggestions about directly putting them on the front, but I don't know how to do it either.
Close button and all other functionalities that I need work but this don't.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my program was neither downloading nor storing the fancybox_sprite.png, which holds the images of prev, next and close buttons. when I first initiated fancybox, it has given a couple of errors, which told me that it couldn't access to some background photos. Thinking that those are unnecessary, I deleted those lines of code in order to not to get any errors. I stumbled upon to this question, it had my answer: [Fancybox 2 arrows not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304488/fancybox-2-arrows-not-showing-up) 
just downloaded the image, and it works.